# Running a linux command against Icinga2 macro variable in mail script?

Tags: monitoring, icinga

It looks like some macros have been dropped between [Icinga1](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/macrolist.html#macrolist-hostduration) and [Icinga2](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/migration#differences-1x-2-runtime-macros)?

For example, I can only add `"HOSTDURATIONSEC" = "$host.duration_sec$",` to my template to then use it in the `mail-host-notification` script like: `State: $HOSTSTATE for $HOSTDURATIONSEC` which tells me how long the host has been in that state. But it only gives me seconds and that's not very helpful at a glance when receiving alerts.

Because [`HOSTDURATION`](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/macrolist.html#macrolist-hostduration) is no longer available or not yet implemented, I've tried converting the seconds to something more readable using functions and other bash attempts within that `mail-host-notification` but it doesn't seem to work.

I'd like to be able to create a new variable in that script maybe using a command from a linux package timetrans like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
SECS=$HOSTDURATIONSEC
CONVERTSECONDS=`timetrans -c $SECS`
eval $CONVERTSECONDS
$HRTIME=`eval $CONVERTSECONDS`

template=`cat <<TEMPLATE
Date/Time: $SHORTDATETIME (EST)

Notification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE

Host: $HOSTALIAS
Address: $HOSTADDRESS
State: $HOSTSTATE for $HRTIME

------------------------------------------
New Jersey DC Icinga Monitoring

Additional Info: $HOSTOUTPUT

Notes on this device:
$HOSTNOTES

Comments: $NOTIFICATIONAUTHORNAME $NOTIFICATIONCOMMENT
TEMPLATE
`
```

...but like the attempts I've tried using functions to convert the seconds variable `$HOSTDURATIONSEC`, it's not working. I'm tried in many ways, but it seems to me that Icinga isn't passing those `env`'s set in the template.

```
  env = {
    "NOTIFICATIONTYPE" = "$notification.type$"
    "HOSTALIAS" = "$host.display_name$",
    "HOSTADDRESS" = "$address$",
    "HOSTSTATE" = "$host.state$",
    "HOSTNOTES" = "$host.notes$",
    "HOSTDURATIONSEC" = "$host.duration_sec$",
    "LONGDATETIME" = "$icinga.long_date_time$",
    "SHORTDATETIME" = "$icinga.short_date_time$",
    "HOSTOUTPUT" = "$host.output$",
    "NOTIFICATIONAUTHORNAME" = "$notification.author$",
    "NOTIFICATIONCOMMENT" = "$notification.comment$",
    "HOSTDISPLAYNAME" = "$host.display_name$",
    "USEREMAIL" = "$user.email$"
  }
```

Of course, anything I added to this list like `"SHORTDATETIME" = "$icinga.short_date_time$",`, `"HOSTNOTES" = "$host.notes$",`, etc. are working, but I'm having trouble trying to run linux commands against those variables in the script. Am I missing something? Anyone know where I'm going wrong? Any/All help is appreciated.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? If my logic is flawed. I'd appreciate fair reasons and consideration. That doesn't help anyone.

Comment: By philosophy and design voting happens unattributed and **neither voting up nor voting down requires any mandatory additional explanation**. Without a comment to the contrary one or more *possible* reasons for a down vote can be found in the tooltip that appears when your mouse pointer hoovers over the down button: *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. That may or may not reflect the actual & private reason of whoever did cast a vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd leave such calculation tricks inside the notification scripts. Since you are not working with Icinga 2 internals, it doesn't makes sense to fiddle with a function.

What I noticed in your script is:

```
$HRTIME=`eval $CONVERTSECONDS`
```

Corrent would be:

```
HRTIME=`eval $CONVERTSECONDS`
```

Btw. if you are using `timetrans` by the package `dnssec-tools`, it is in `/usr/sbin`, so not in path of the icinga/nagios user.

Modified working example:

```
#!/bin/sh
SECS=$HOSTDURATIONSEC
TIMEREADABLE=`/usr/sbin/timetrans -c $SECS`

template=`cat <<TEMPLATE
Date/Time: $SHORTDATETIME (EST)

Notification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE

Host: $HOSTALIAS
Address: $HOSTADDRESS
State: $HOSTSTATE for $TIMEREADABLE

------------------------------------------
New Jersey DC Icinga Monitoring

Additional Info: $HOSTOUTPUT

Notes on this device:
$HOSTNOTES

Comments: $NOTIFICATIONAUTHORNAME $NOTIFICATIONCOMMENT
TEMPLATE
`
/usr/bin/printf "%b" "$template"
```

To be called via:

```
HOSTDURATIONSEC=123 sh test.sh
```

P.S.(1) If you are missing a macro in Icinga 2, open an issue to suggest it

P.S.(2) Don't call other users a coward, that is not nice!